# GitLab CI / CD limitations or better solution?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

This question is more informational: I have an project runned via Django, Gunicorn, Supervisor, also PostgreSQL Database, Redis Cache, nginx for storage and some other.

The question is, it is possible to run this tools with CI/CD, but outside container (Docker, e.t.c). Like when Gitlab get push/merge request on production branch (protected), update the code and if this tools is not started, then start them. Already started tools can get command to check configurations, tool like Django have hotspot reload and no need to be restarted by killing a process.

Like, is there any way to do that? May be use shell script or something to copy code? Gitlab and project runned on same machine (currently manually, site hosted at `site_url.com`, gitlab at `git.site_url.com`).

Because in standart way container only capable to run tests, while I looking in any automatical way to just update code.

Or should I use then other tools for that, it it not possible to make this process automatic?

*If you know any guide, please link it.*

*Note: Gitlab used because several peoples contribute to code.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this all by using a Gitlab Runner of the [executor type '**Shell**'](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) installed on the target machine.

Or you could use the ['**SSH**' executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/ssh.html) and you can install the runner on another machine and connect to your target machine.

In your job(s) you can use commands as if you where SSH-ing into the target machine like this:

```
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: none

stages:
  - update-code
  - restart-services

update-code:
  stage: update-code
  script: 
    - cd /mydir
    - git pull

reload-nginx:
  stage: restart-services
  script: 
    - service nginx reload

restart-redis
  stage: restart-services
  script:
    - service redis restart
```

[This section](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/#i-am-not-sure) has some pointers on what executor to pick. You want to automate manual tasks so my advice is to use SSH or Shell, if you want a clean and reproducible test environment, use Docker or Kubernetes executor.

Using `variables: GIT_STRATEGY: none` makes sure your runner doesn't clone your repo first to run tests etc. (this is default behaviour in a 'normal' CI setup).

Comment: This look good, so as I understand first `cd /path/to/my/code` I locate to folder where my code it is and with `git pull` I update my code to latest version, after that I do all manual work to restart/reconfigure any services I need, right?

Comment: That is correct. An alternative would be to change the default location of your Gitlab CI worker dir but I would try this first

Comment: @XCanG I added a small tweak to make sure your CI doesn't clone your repo in its working dir first.

Comment: What does it change? In my final yaml I trigger all this code only when I have an update on production branch, so it don't affect with any pull/merge on development branch.

Comment: Normally your code gets checked out in a build directory, you do a git pull by hand so no need for that. If this works for you, please mark as answer please.

Comment: I can't say if GIT_STRATEGY is actually work, but other part - yes, so, yeh, I will mark it as answer and close question.